# Calling a Rust libary through a thread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, rust

I'm making a Qt frontend for a Rust libary which exposes a C++ function that blocks the execution thread it resides in, but allows to pass a callback function for communication between the two ends.

So I thought of using Qt's threading technologies to make the library execution on another thread, and I'd like to do it *with the least amount of modifications as possible to the Rust library*.

This is my approach using QThreads:

backend.cpp:

```cpp
typedef void(*callback_t)(void *,const char *);
extern "C" call_rust_library(const char *config, void *cb_data, callback_t cb);

template<typename T>
void call_wrapper(void *ptr, const char*data) {
    (*static_cast<T*>(ptr))(data);
}

class BackEnd : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void do_computations(ConfigObject *config) {
        //...parse configuration from the frontend...
        char* parsed_configuration;
        BackEnd* backend = this;

        auto callback = [backend](char* data) {
            //...process obtained data from the library...
            QString type,contents;
            backend->emit send_message(type,contents);
        }

        call_rust_library(parsed_configuration,(void *)&callback,call_wrapper<decltype(callback)>);
    }
signals:
    void send_message(QString type, QString contents);
}
```

frontend.cpp:

```cpp
class FrontEnd : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
    ConfigObject *config;
public slots:
    void process_message(QString type, QString contents) {
        //...do GUI things with the message
    }
private slots:
    void on_request_start_thread() {
        // called by a GUI event
        BackEnd* backend = new BackEnd;
        backend->moveToThread(&thread);
        connect(&thread,&QThread::finished,backend,&QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this,&FrontEnd::run_thread,backend,&BackEnd::do_computations);
        connect(backend,&BackEnd::send_message,frontend,&FrontEnd::process_message);
        emit run_thread(config)
    }
signals:
    void run_thread(ConfigObject *config);
}
```

However I have a couple of problems with this:

- First off, nothing from the backend gets executed. If I don't move the BackEnd object to another thread it does seem to run everything but crashes somewhere on a system library (my best guess is that is because Qt forbids blocking the GUI thread and/or handling GUI functions from another thread).
- How would Qt be able to abort the Rust library execution thread? (via closing the application or the user clicking a button) The Rust library doesn't seem to expose any mechanism to stop its execution, so I'm wondering if I have to make modifications to the library to expose a function to abort whatever it's doing.

Recently I've found [this example repository](https://gitlab.com/bloom42/research/rust_gui_ecosystem/tree/master/qt_cpp) that allows for binding Qt with Rust libraries but doesn't seem to delve into multithreading, and might require my project to be ported from CMake to qmake. But from my understanding the Rust executions should be residing in another thread, so I'm not sure how is it achieved here.

Comment: I don't see thread.start() being called? If the rust function doesn't allow cancellation, QThread::terminate() might be the only option, leaving a potentially unclean state behind. Or consider moving the rust function to a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is correct, save for the fact that I forgot a `thread->start()` call at the end of `on_request_thread()` function.

The crash happened because of a problem while parsing the ConfigObject, so it had nothing to do with the making of a thread.